# Switching to ahead boolean expression evaluation in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to switch ahead evaluation of booleans in Python 3.4.3. Currently my code raises an IndexError exception. Say the following one

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
if (len(lst)>3) & (lst[3]<2):
    print('hello')
```

gives the "IndexError: list index out of range"
Is there any way to get such an option in Python 3.4.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why are you using the & (which is `the bitwise and of x and y`), and not the and?

should be:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
if (len(lst)>3) and (lst[3]<2):
    print('hello')
```